# Converting from a dynamic data type in c# to a .net Object

Tags: c#, json

I have a method that receives some data from a 3rd party. The data is a JSON object (not a string, I tried receiving as a string and data was not accessable - the data property was null)

```
[HttpPost]
 [Route("com/sendemail")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> SendEmail(dynamic data)
 {
       mailData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmailTemplate>(data);
 }
```

I am trying to get it into a .net object which is needed to be passed into another function I dont control. It has to be an EmailTemplate object, which is defined as:

```
public class EmailTemplate
{
        public string From { get; set; }
        public string To { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string EmailHtml { get; set; }
}
```

mailData is of type EmailTemplate. The Deserialize object call fails because that method requires a string, which this isnt. Ive tried other methods, such as

```
mailData = (EmailTemplate)data;
```

and

```
mailData.To = data.To
```

but neither work. Any pointers gratefully received.

PS. Heres what the data looks like in visual studio

[image]

Comment: Why do you use dynamic and doesn't use the type you're expecting in your controller method?

Comment: I did this because I dont know the object type. I dont know its a EmailTemplate, all I know is it happens to look like one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller couldn't accept a string, because (I assume) the request's content-type is 'application/json' and the framework couldn't convert it to a string. You should change your controller's `data` parameter type to `EmailTemplate`:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("com/sendemail")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SendEmail([FromBody] EmailTemplate data)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: I hadnt realised or thought about it like this. I started from not knowing what the object passed in was, just that it looked like an EmailTemplate, so I set about trying to convert an 'unknown'. But, if it looks like a duck, and quacks like a duck.....       This worked thanks, is obvious now, but left me stuck and frustrated for a few hours.

Answer (score 2):

When your class matches the Json-object that is sent, this will work:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SendEmail([FromBody]EmailTemplate data)
```

When you use your dynamic approach, you need to access the dynamic objects members and create your .NET object with them.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SendEmail([FromBody]dynamic data)
{
    mailData = new EmailTemplate {
        From      = data.From,
        To        = data.To,
        Subject   = data.Subject,
        EmailHtml = data.EmailHtml
    };
}
```